# How set variable as date type in psql?

Tags: postgresql, variables, psql

`to_date` can convert string into date:

```
select  to_date('2024-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
  to_date   
------------
 2024-01-01
(1 row)
```

Let's check the data type:

```
select  pg_typeof(to_date('2024-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'));
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 date
```

Why can't set an variable as date type?

```
\set mydate to_date('2024-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
select :mydate;
ERROR:  column "yyyy" does not exist
LINE 1: select to_date(2024-01-01,YYYY-MM-DD);
                                  ^
Time: 0.212 ms
```

Comment: That's not a Postgres database variable, that's a psql client variable. Which doesn't have a data type, it's just text. (Although I'm not sure why it discards the apostrophe)

Comment: How to make the psql client variable as date type then?

Comment: Typing `\set` shows the value for mydate as: `mydate = 'to_date(2024-01-01,YYYY-MM-DD);'`, which should explain why that is not a date....

Comment: Why do you need a variable in a client like psql? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\set` command is not part of PostgreSQL itself, but a feature of the `psql` command-line utility. The [relevant section in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES) includes this:

> psql provides variable substitution features similar to common Unix command shells. Variables are simply name/value pairs, where the value can be any string of any length.

So, there is no such thing as a "date variable" within this system. The meta-command `\set mydate to_date('2024-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')` assigns a *string value* to the variable named `mydate`. When you then use `:mydate`, that string is simply *inserted verbatim* at that point in the SQL to be run.

You might think that would still be fine, because the result would be to run this:

```
select to_date('2024-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

But what actually happens is that the single quotes are treated specially *by the `\set` meta-command*, so that what ends up in the variable is `to_date(2024-01-01, YYYY-MM-DD)`, and the SQL you're trying to run is this:

```
select to_date(2024-01-01,YYYY-MM-DD);
```

This explains the error - `2024-01-01` is a valid expression, a funny way of writing `2022`; but `YYYY` without any quotes around looks like a column name.

---

So, if you really want to use the string interpolation feature in this case, you need to escape the quotes. I haven't tested, but I think that should look like this:

```
\set mydate 'to_date(\'2024-01-01\',\'YYYY-MM-DD\')'
```

However, remember that this *is not storing the date in the variable*, it's just saving a string to "copy-and-paste" into future queries.

```
select :mydate;
```

Now becomes:

```
select to_date('2024-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

---

As [pointed out by Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77906350/157957), you can also use `\gset` to store *the result of a query* into a variable:

```
select to_date('2024-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AS mydate \gset
```

Again, though, *it's just saving a string*, so the above is useless: it's the same as `\set mydate '2024-01-01'`. It might be useful if your actual value is more dynamic, though:

```
select CURRENT_DATE AS mydate \gset
```

This results in `mydate` containing *the string representation* of today's date, *without any quotes around it*. To use it in queries, you need to use the `:'variable_name'` syntax, so that it is correctly quoted in the query:

```
select :'mydate' as test;
```

This results in something like:

```
select '2024-01-30' as test;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `\gset` for that:

```
SELECT to_date('2024-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AS mydate \gset

SELECT :mydate;

 ?column? 
══════════
     2022
(1 row)

SELECT :'mydate';

  ?column?  
════════════
 2024-01-01
(1 row)
```

`\gset` uses the column alias as variable name and assigns the query result to that variable.

The first query, after substitution, looks like this:

```
SELECT 2024-01-01;
```

So it is treated as numbers, and the result is 2022.

The second query escapes the variable as a string literal and produces the desired result.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this still doesn't actually store *a date* into the variable, it converts the result back to a string. So in this example, it just acts as `\set mydate '2024-01-01'`, and any use in queries that need a date rather than a string will still need to perform the `to_date` operation again. To put it simply, `select pg_typeof(:'mydate')` will report `text`, not `date`.

Comment: I've added a note on `\gset`, and why it doesn't actually do anything useful in this example, to my answer.

Comment: @IMSoP The question didn't make clear to me what the user actually wanted (and I am still not certain, although your answer seems to fit the bill).

Comment: Sure, that's why I went with first and foremost explaining what their attempt actually did. The tip of `\gset` is a good one, but only if the user doesn't just misunderstand its meaning again, and think it's doing something more than it does.